# html5 required attribute on non supported browsers

Tags: jquery, html, required

I have a web application which makes use of the HTML5 `required` attribute frequently. However Safari and ie 8/9 do not support this attribute. Is there a jQuery plugin that will force the behaviour on non-compatible browsers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a very versatile and lightweight (once minified) engine that works cross-browser including ie8!

http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/

Answer (score 7):

This works without any plugin (JQuery only):

```
<script>

    // fix for IE < 11
    if ($("<input />").prop("required") === undefined) {
        $(document).on("submit", function(e) {
            $(this)
                    .find("input, select, textarea")
                    .filter("[required]")
                    .filter(function() { return this.value == ''; })
                    .each(function() {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).css({ "border-color":"red" });
                        alert( $(this).prev('label').html() + " is required!");
                    });
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: how would you change this to check each time submit is clicked? To get rid of the red border if the field was filled.

Answer (score 4):

You could shim it simply...

```
if ($("<input />").prop("required") === undefined) {
    $(document).on("submit", function(event) {
         $(this)
           .find("input, select, textarea")
           .filter("[required]")
           .filter(function() { return this.value; })
           .each(function() {
               // Handle them.
           });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code actually contains a bug, as `.filter(function() { return this.value; })` won't include only empty form fields but EXCLUDE all empty form fields, so that you'd end up with all fields that are required and have content, instead of all required form fields that lack content.

Comment: @S.B. You're right. If that is against your goals, omit that line.

Comment: @alex You cannot just omit that line and then problem solved. It will handle every "required" field, even it's not empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [h5validate](https://github.com/ericelliott/h5Validate) which does exactly what you need.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('form').h5Validate();
});
</script>
```

Comment: they seem to have quite a few issues with their test code and documentation lacks some of the features we need like no spaces or symbols

Comment: do you just need to check for the 'required' attribute? Maybe would be better know more details and build one accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a very simple jQuery plugin for this. It just adds client side validation to a forms using the 'required' attribute.

https://github.com/garyv/jQuery-Validation-plugin

After including the plugin, you can call the validate() in jQuery's document ready function or at the end of the html body.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').validate();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: when you say 2. Call $('form').validate(); how to do that? simply add $('form').validate();' inside the page? I tried your plugin but i cant get it to work

Comment: I updated the comment with an example. 

My guess is you were trying to call validate() before including the plugin or before the <form> element.

JavaScript runs very sequentially - so you have to include plugin and the HTML <form> before using either of them in code. This is a basic part of how HTML and JavaScript works. jQuery's document ready function is a common way of handling this - http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - all it basically does is delay running code until after the web page loads, so that it can reference any HTML on the page.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE8, what's the point of using this then? IE9 and above support HTML5 validation.

Comment: Actually, this does work in IE8.

I recently added a [test suite](https://garyv.s3.amazonaws.com/html5_validation/test/test.html),

and I have a [screenshot](http://f.cl.ly/items/2j2B1b1o0x3x1Z3e0A2F/ie8-html5-validaiton.jpg) of it running in IE8.