# jQuery submit function called even when HTML 5 validation stops form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

The following function is called every time a form is submitted:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    // Some code
});
```

However I have the following HTML 5 attribute in some of the fields in my form:

```
required="required"
```

That means that if I don't fill in the field, the form is not submitted.

Follows that the previous function is not run. That's true in all the browsers except IE8. Yes, because in IE8 even if the field is empty and the form is not submitted succesfully, the "submit" function is run anyway.

I'm using jQuery 1.9 and Bootstrap 2.0.4

Why does this problem happen only in IE8? What work around can I use?

Comment: Required isn't a bootstrap thing, it's an html5 thing.  It's not supported on IE8/9 (and partial in Safari).  See here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation.  Here's an SO answer for how to handle in browsers that don't support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479573/html5-required-attribute-on-non-supported-browsers

Answer (score 0):

The workaround you can use is the prevent the default behavior of the form submit as such:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   // Some code
});
```

The required attribute is not supported by IE8, nor IE9. 
Only IE10 supports this attribute.