# Check for empty form fields in this field only

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, this

I have this code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(":input").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "")
    alert("Empty Fields!!");
  });
});
```

It works great but when I have more than one form on a page, it checks all forms. I wan't to check only the submitted form using the "this" selector. How shall I implement the "this" selector in my code to check only the submitted form?

I cannot use any id's or classes, only the "this" selector.

Comment: as side notes, if you don't need to suport IE<10, you should use `required` attribute ***and*** `$(this).val()` is just more boring way to write `this.value` ;)  As kind of polyfill for required attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479573/html5-required-attribute-on-non-supported-browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the form submit handler you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the form which raised the event. Once you have that you could use `find`:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "")
            alert("Empty Fields!!");
    });
});
```

Or a contextual selector:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(":input", this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "")
            alert("Empty Fields!!");
    });
});
```

To retrieve the related `input` elements.

Comment: Rory, do you know how I can filter out all submit buttons in my code?

Comment: You could use `:not(button)`, or manually place a class on the elements you want.