# Display required fields through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So for HTML5 there's a new field called `required` like from here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Is there a way for me to trigger this manually for a specific div? This is because I have 5 checkboxes in my form, and I want to make sure the user selects at least one. There're solutions online for displaying an alert, but I want a `required` box like in the examples above.

Thank you!

Comment: For a `<div>`?  It might be helpful to see your code.

Comment: I want it to be displayed just above one of the checkboxes, which I have the ID/Class for

Comment: I think you are confused as to what the `required` attribute does--  it doesn't have anything to do with displaying the word "required" anywhere.

Comment: It's the required attribute like from here: `<input type="text" name="usrname" required>`, is it not?

Comment: Yes, but that won't display the word "required" in your UI.  See the example in your own link.  It simply prevents a form from being submitted if any required field has no value.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. i want to display the `please fill out this field` error box if none of the checkboxes are ticked.

Comment: Please add some code-- it is not efficient to talk about this in the abstract-- context is important.

Comment: `required` doesn't do that. It makes that specific input required, it's not conditional on whether other items are filled in or checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation). This needs to be done before the form is submitted, so I do it in click handlers on the checkboxes.

```js
var checkboxes = $("#yourForm :checkbox");

function setCheckboxValidity(msg) {
  checkboxes.each(function() {
    this.setCustomValidity(msg);
  });
}

setCheckboxValidity("select at least one");

checkboxes.click(function() {
  if (checkboxes.is(":checked")) {
    setCheckboxValidity("");
  } else {
    setCheckboxValidity("select at least one");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="yourForm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" name="B" value="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" name="C" value="3">3
  <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: My understanding is that the browser will automatically report validity and prevent submission if any field has a non-empty custom validity set. You can use `reportValidity()` to display the messages independently of the automatic submission.

Comment: Welcome. Do you know if reportValidity has to be used. It seems that the notification only appears after the second click. But since i changed your code the cause may be my doing.

Comment: I think `event.preventDefault()` in your code prevents it from displaying the messages automatically, since it's part of the default submission process.

Comment: @surfmuggle Take a look at the examples in my MDN link. They never call `reportValidity()` or `preventDefault()`.

Comment: That still has preventDefault.

Comment: Although that should prevent the form from submitting. Need to investigate.

Comment: @surfmuggle Apparently it needs to be set before the submit event occurs, so I moved it to a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').click(function() {
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

      if(!checked) {
        alert("Check one please");
        return false;
      }
      else {
         alert("Okey");
      }

    });
});

</script>


<ul>
   <li><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 1" required><label>1</label></li>
   <li><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 2" required><label>2</label></li>
   <li><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 3" required><label>3</label></li>
   <li><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 4" required><label>4</label></li>
   <li><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 5" required><label>5</label></li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Test" id="test">


</body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the html-5 `required` attribute is a way for [clientside-form-validation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#clientside-form-validation). Be aware that [older browsers need a shim to use required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479573/). From your question i got these requirements

1. my form has 5 checkboxes and I want to make sure the user selects at
   least one
2. [I want to be able to] trigger [`required`] manually for a specific div
3. I want a required box like in the examples above.

#### Brief overview of the code

Below the checkboxes are inside  `<div id="myDiv">...</div>`

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <p id="info">Please select at least one option!</p>
   <input name="one" type="checkbox" value="1">One
   <input name="two" type="checkbox" value="2">Two 
   <input name="three" type="checkbox" value="3" required>Three is required
   <input name="four" type="checkbox" value="4">Four
   <input name="five" type="checkbox" value="5">Five
</div>
<button onclick="checkOptions()">Check options</button>
```

To get the checkboxes inside the div this javascript can be used

```
// select the inputs inside myDiv
var inputs =  document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("input"); 

// for each input test if it is a checkbox AND checked 
if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked)
{
     checkBoxes.push(inputs[i]);
} 

// if not one single checkbox was checked the new array has length <1
// create a message
if(checkBoxes.length < 1)
{
    notifyUser();
}
```

#### Example Snippet with full code

```js
function getBoxValues()
{        
  var checkBoxes = [];         
  var yourDiv = document.getElementById("checkOptions");
  var inputs = yourDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");        

  for(var i=0; inputs[i]; ++i)
  {            
    if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked)
    {        
      checkBoxes.push(inputs[i]);
    }
  }        
  return checkBoxes;
}    

function checkOptions()
{
  var checkBoxes = getBoxValues();        
  if(checkBoxes.length < 1)
  {
    notifyUser();
  }
}

function notifyUser()
{
    var info = document.getElementById("info");
    info.style.visibility = "visible";
    info.style.color = "red";
}
```

```css
#info { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div id="checkOptions">
   <p id="info">Please select at least one option!</p>
   <input name="one" type="checkbox" value="1">One
   <input name="two" type="checkbox" value="2">Two 
   <input name="three" type="checkbox" value="3" required>Three is required
   <input name="four" type="checkbox" value="4">Four
   <input name="five" type="checkbox" value="5">Five
</div>
<button onclick="checkOptions()">Check options</button>
```

The above gives a brief overview how to make sure that one checkbox inside a div is selected (see your requirement 1) and to notifiy the user (requirement 3). By calling the function `getBoxValues()` you can test manually if one checkbox was selected (requirement 2).

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: For me to later take a look:  plnkr.co/edit/8yNWEUVmJMdA3w7X8kYZ?p=preview