# Getting HTML5 Required Fields on Non Supported Browsers Without JQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I use several required fields on my website, but browsers that do not support HTML5 do not support them. How can I work around that? A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479573/html5-required-attribute-on-non-supported-browsers) but specifically for JQuery. I do not use JQuery on my site, but Angular 1.4 for the front end along with ui-bootstrap.

Comment: Don't kid yourself: if you use Angular 1.4, you are using jQuery. From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): *"If jQuery is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or **jqLite**"*. Guess why. *"(it)...allows AngularJS to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way."*

Comment: Ah interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). Form and controls provide validation services, so that the user can be notified of invalid input before submitting a form. This is built-in to the AngularJS framework using jqLite.